# Waxed floorboards now too slippery - how to keep look but create some friction?

Tags: finishing, sanding

With hindsight I perhaps shouldn't have done this, but it cannot be undone, so I am looking for the best way to remedy the situation!

Restoring some old pine floorboards, I sanded them down and created a very smooth surface. They looked very dull and grey however, so I applied a wax finish, which brought out the colour very well. The end result looked very good.

However, walking around on them I discovered that in certain types of shoe there isn't quite enough grip. Its not so bad that you can skate, its just a little unsettling.

So, I am wondering what I can do to create more friction. I imagine if I used an electric sander I could take off 1mm and remove the wax, but I would rather not. Is there maybe some tool/technique that can slightly roughen or indent the surface? My best idea so far is to try a very coarse sandpaper, but I think this probably won't be enough.

By the way, this is an outdoor gazebo/bandstand type of structure (covered). Putting down a rug etc isn't practical.

Comment: There are some lower-friction floor finishes available, but TBH I think you have to try them out to see so they're a hard sell — what if you get some and it's still not good enough? Here in Europe we have specs for the safety of floor tiles but I have firsthand experience of the standard not being worth a damn as a newly tiled floor we discovered was dangerously slippery if your shoes were damp from rain outside, never mind if there was a spill so the tiles were actually wet. The basic vinyl it replaced was a far better!

Comment: This might be more appropriate for DIY.SE?

Comment: @jdv, obviously this is within our purview but the OP is likely to get more (and possibly better) responses there than here!

Comment: @GraphussupportsMonica indeed, which was the thinking behind my comment, actually.

Comment: OK understood. Is there a way to move the question, or is it a case of copy & paste?